# Run-Time Check Failure #0 После записи указателя на метод класса

Tags: c++, ооп, callback

Делаю колбэк на изменения размеров окна, и реагирования на изменение размера рендерера. Хорошо, объявил `typedef`, класс окна и класс рендерера находятся в разных библиотеках. Сделал объявление:

```
class renderer;
typedef bool(__thiscall renderer::*renderer_resize_callback_t)(unsigned, unsigned) const;
```

Далее, после того как рендерер был создан, записываю указатель на метод ресайза в класс окна:

```
class API_WINDOWS window
{
    ...

    renderer *p_renderer_;
    renderer_resize_callback_t m_resize_callback_t_;

public:
    ...

    void set_resize_callback(direct2d::renderer_resize_callback_t resize_callback_t);
};
```

```
void window::set_resize_callback(const renderer_resize_callback_t resize_callback_t)
{
    m_resize_callback_t_ = resize_callback_t;
}
```

```
class API_RENDERER renderer
{
protected:
    ID2D1Factory* p_factory_;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* p_render_target_;

public:
    renderer(const void* window_handle, int w, int h);
    ~renderer();

    void draw() const;
    bool __thiscall resize_target(unsigned width, unsigned height) const;

    renderer() = delete;
    renderer(const renderer&) = delete;
    renderer(const renderer&&) = delete;
    renderer& operator=(const renderer&) = delete;
    renderer& operator=(const renderer&&) = delete;
};
```

```
bool __thiscall renderer::resize_target(const unsigned width, const unsigned height) const
{
    const HRESULT result = p_render_target_->Resize(D2D1::SizeU(width, height));
    return !(FAILED(result));
}
```

Далее пытаюсь записать указатель на класс рендерера и на метод ресайза в класс вызовом метода `set_resize_callback`:

```
window wnd(1024, 768);
renderer renderer(wnd.get_window_handle(), 1024, 768);

wnd.set_renderer(&renderer);
wnd.set_resize_callback(&renderer::resize_target);
```

Но после того как будет вызван метод, произойдет исключение:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention.

Как я понял в нем говорится о том, что не совпадает соглашение о вызовах, и оно повредило стэк. Но как? В определении прототипа явно указано соглашение, так же как и у метода.

Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: А где код `set_resize_callback` и `resize_target` и `renderer`? Зачем там `__thiscall`?

Comment: `__thiscall` был добавлен после того как я получил данное исключение без явного указания соглашений о вызовах, подумав что это исправит проблему, но это не дало абсолютно никакого эффекта.

Comment: *"класс окна и класс рендерера находятся в разных библиотеках"* - а эти библиотеки собраны с одинаковыми настройками?

Comment: Они собраны идентично друг другу.

Comment: А если просто вызвать `renderer.resize_target` то проблемы не будет? Также следует проверить, что значения указателей в объекте window остались правильные и соотствуют тем, которые можно получить внутри библиотеки renderer.

Comment: @VTT: Вызов не создает исключения, но вот при выходе из приложения, происходит тоже самое. Вызывается `__fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE);`

Comment: Ну можно еще попробовать пересобрать все с `/vmg /vmv` чтобы защититься от потенциальных проблем с объявлением указателя на метод неполного класса.

Comment: @VTT: Тоже не помогает... Уже не знаю стоит ли так делать, раздельные библиотеки.

Comment: Похоже я понял в чем проблема, при отладке уже в который раз, стал замечать следующее, `у метода ... нет адреса, возможно это вызвано оптимизацией`, от этого можно избавиться?

Comment: Ну уж не знаю что там пошло не так, но без минимального примера тут вряд ли чем-то можно помоч